# iphone:How to animate uibeizserpath set stroke color?

Tags: iphone, uibezierpath, stroke, cashapelayer

I have an one view with horizontal and vertical beizer paths.The resulting view looks like the foloowing[image]

Now on touch of the view if user has touched the one of the path,I have to change the color of that path by animation that means on touch of a path ,path's storke color will be changed animaticllay.

I am able to do it with the normal way ,that means when user touch the path I am able to change the color but not with the animation effect.

I have created the sub class of UIBeizerPath with properties like defaultStorkeColor,SelectedStorkeColor and I am manipulating them in the drawrect.

My drawrect is

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

{

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


for(BCBeizerPath * path in pathsArray)
{
    if(path.selected)
    {
        [path.selectedStrokeColor set];

    }
    else 
    {
        [path.defaultStrokeColor set];   
    }

    [path stroke];


}
```

}

Please help me in implementing that.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try this code but hit with a same scenario before, which I had resolved by doing something like the below:

In `-drawRect` draw these patterns over a `CAShapeLayer` using `UIBezierPath` and add it to your `CustomView`'s `layer`

```
[self.layer addSubLayer:self.shapeLayer_main];
```

Then get the frame of the rect you wish to draw the stroke using

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];    
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];    
    //Check in which rect in your view contains the touch location    
    //Then call the method to draw the stroke with the detected rect as the parameter    
    [self drawStrokeWithRect:touchedRect];    
}
```

In the method,

```
-(void)drawStrokeWithRect:(CGRect )touchedRect {
//Create a shapeLayer with desired strokeColor, lineWidth and path(A UIBezierPath)
//This is the layer your are going to animate
//Add this shapeLayer to your self.shapeLayer_main added to the customView's layer
CAShapeLayer * shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 4;
shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor;
shapeLayer.fillColor = transparentColor.CGColor;
shapeLayer.path = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:touchedRect]CGPath];
[self.shapeLayer_main addSublayer:shapeLayer];

//Adding Animation to the ShapeLayer
CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
drawAnimation.duration = 1.0;
drawAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];

[shapeLayer addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"StrokeAnimation"];
}
```

Every time you tap the view, a rect is drawn with the stroke color you gave with the animation.